# cron job failing at unzip of files

Tags: unix, sh, unzip

I have a shell script that I can run successfully from the command line.

However, when I try to run the same script inside a cron job, it runs successfully up to a portion where unzipping of files occurs and then fails at the unzip portion.

The echo of "UNZIP FILES" occurs and then the process fails.

Any ideas why I'm able to run the script successfully from the command line but not as a cron and why it might be failing at the unzip portion?

Here's the unzip portion of the script:

```
# Unzip the zipped files that were brought down
echo "\n*** UNZIP FILES ***"
cd $FILES_DIR
for z in *.zip; do unzip $z; done
```

Comment: What is the value of `$FILES_DIR`? What are the error message, if any? What is the `$PATH` set in crontab? Or do you modify it in your script? Are there any `.zip` files in `$FILES_DIR`?

Comment: ah ha - very good questions, thank you - looks like $PATH is different for crontab as opposed to when I login to the shell directly.  Is there a "right" way to set $PATH in crontab like when I open the shell?  Or, should I just set $PATH in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$PATH` was different in `crontab` as opposed to the command line.

I updated the `$PATH` in `crontab` to be the same as when I launch the command line and then was able to execute the crontab no problem.

Thanks Zsolt Botykai for the good questions as they led me to the answer.